# How to get a value from arrays with php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have these data array stored in variable `$ids`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "472"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "475"
  }
  [26]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "498"
  }
}
```

How can I get value of each id? I tried with `for` loop but it's not working.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
   echo "ID is " . $ids['id'][$i];
}
```

Comment: That won't work @splash look at the keys

Comment: You need `foreach($ids as $id){ echo $id["id"];}`

Comment: @splash58, it returns an error `Undefined offset: 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach($ids as $id)
{
   echo "ID is " . $id['id'];
}
```

Because your keys are are not like `1,2,3....`, the `for` loop won't work, but `foreach` will.

Comment: A for loop can work but it's much harder.

Comment: Not too bad but ugly and unreadable. https://3v4l.org/eUBAg

Comment: Yes that is a good one. But if the max key would be higher this would loop lots of keys that is unnecessary. But it's a good solution non the less

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-sequential array order you can use foreach instead of for loop.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ViHoW

```
<?php

$datas = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '472'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 475
    ),
    26 => array(
        'id' => '498'
    )
);

foreach ($datas as $data) {
    echo $data['id'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

or if you really want to use for loop do it like this.

Demo v2: https://3v4l.org/EYlft

```
<?php

$datas = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '472'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '475'
    ),
    26 => array(
        'id' => '498'
    )
);


$datas = array_values($datas); // array_values will re-index your array to 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
$data_count = count($datas); // make it a habit not to use function in for loop header to prevent multiple execution.

for ($i = 0; $i < $data_count; $i++) {
    echo $datas[$i]['id'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For demo purpose. This is how you can do it with a for loop and with the array still intact. (No array_values messing with the keys).

```
$ids = array(0=>
array( 
"id"=>"472"
),
1=>
array(
"id"=>"475"
),
26=>
array(
"id"=>"498"
));

$keys = array_keys($ids);

For($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++){
    Echo $ids[$keys[$i]]["id"] ."\n";
}
```

I use array_keys to get the keys or $ids.
Then I for loop the keys and use the keys as key in $ids.
Yes it's messy...

https://3v4l.org/eUBAg